# Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange<String>' to expected argument type 'Range<_>'

Tags: swift, range

I want the user to be able to change the minNum and maxNum if he want to (if not the default value are 0 and 100) and the numberGenerated should be a random number between the minNum and the maxNum.

For example : if the user set for minNum 100 and maxNum 200, when he click the Generate button it should display a random number between 100 and 200. [View Screen of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGCr8.png)

```
func numberGenerator() {
    var minValue = minNum.text ?? String(0)
    var maxValue = maxNum.text ?? String(100)
    numberGenerated = Int.random(in: minValue ... maxValue)
}
```

I got an error in the numberGenerated = Int... line which say : 
Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange' to expected argument type 'Range<_>'

Comment: `minValue` and `maxValue` need to be of type `Int`, not `String`.

Comment: try `let minValue = Int(minNum.text!) ?? 0`